# How to return back to the first plot in R-Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am working on an R-Shiny Application. I have used the following code(demo code) to interact with the plot.

```
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Title"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
     ),
     mainPanel(
       plotOutput("graph", width = "100%", click = "plot_click"),
       verbatimTextOutput("click_info")
     )
   )
 ) 
 )

 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
   observe({
     output$graph <- renderPlot({
       plot(1, 1)
     })  
   })


   # interaction click in graph  
   observe({
     if(is.null(input$plot_click$x)) return(NULL)
     x <- sample(20:30,1,F)
     isolate({
       output$graph <- renderPlot({
         draw.single.venn(x)
       }) 
     })

   })
 })
 shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

It can change the plot on a mouse click. I want to get back to the very first plot using a reset button. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a reset button to your sidebar. Hope that's helpful. [This link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) provides more info on how to do this type of functionality.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("Reset", label="Reset Graph")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph", width = "100%", click = "plot_click"),
      verbatimTextOutput("click_info")
    )
  )
) 
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  observeEvent(input$Reset,{ output$graph <- renderPlot({ plot(1, 1) }) }, ignoreNULL = F)

  # interaction click in graph  
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$plot_click$x)) return(NULL)
    x <- sample(20:30,1,F)
    isolate({
      output$graph <- renderPlot({
        draw.single.venn(x)
      }) 
    })

  })

})
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: No need to repeat code: `observeEvent(input$Reset,{
    output$graph <- renderPlot({
      plot(1, 1)
    })  
  }, ignoreNULL = F)`

Comment: You can have memory leaks putting rendering and other heavy operations inside observe, try adding a larger dataset, you will see what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will let you know if any problem will occur.

Comment: @olorcain One more thing. What changes I suppose to do to return to the previous plot(not the first one).

Comment: I think it's going to be more difficult to return to a previous user-defined plot that to return to a fixed starting point. You might need to save a list of plot parameters that you can refer back to and load from. I think this should be a new question.